# how to check whether web service url is Soap or REST web service url

Tags: web-services, web, wsdl, httprequest, soapui

I have some web service URLs which I need to test over soapUI  tool but I dont know whether my web service url is SOAP based or REST based in order to create project in SoapUI tool to test web service.

Comment: Without finding this out, it is going to be extremely difficult to construct the test cases. Talk to the whomever created this service - the developer?

Comment: Try the endpoint in the browser and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

By looking the URL its not possible to tell if its REST or SOAP.You need to ask the web service provider about these details. You also need to know the input format/ details you need to send to web service (once you understand REST/SOAP). You can get the wsdl of SOAP webservice by entering `endpointURL?wsdl` (example: http://mywerserviceURL?wsdl)` in the browser.